# VBA code to overwrite cells through moving /shifting up a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i have a data table, as seen from the picture, which changes from time to time. For example if there new data coming up for March'15 i would have to copy and overlap cells from April'14 onwards to March'14. Thereafter i would fill in the information for march'15 on the blank cell that was previously filled with feb'15 information. I was wondering if there is any vba code to help move or shift the range to the preferred row of cells that already has existing data ( more of a code to overlap/ overwrrite cells through moving/shifting up) .
[image: Data Table]

Was thinking of Activecell.offset but i am not sure if it can shift up as a range of cells.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Use this to post your data as text: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html . Also I'm not sure I understand "overlap" in your context. Why doesn't March 15 simply go into the next empty row?

Comment: because the data moves up by one row so the row that contains feb 15 would have been empty so march 15 would go into that empty row @Andre451

Comment: So the row "March 14" is supposed to vanish after the operation?

Comment: Thats right @Andre451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, use a simple loop to copy the values. The last row (13) is overwritten with the empty values of row 14.

```
Public Sub MoveUp()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet ' or the specific sheet

    ' The 12 months
    For y = 2 To 13
        ' Your 7 columns
        For x = 1 To 7
            sh.Cells(y, x) = sh.Cells(y + 1, x)
        Next x
    Next y

    With sh.Cells(13, 1)
        .Select
        ' This only works if your column A contains dates (not strings)
        .Value = DateAdd("m", 1, sh.Cells(12, 1))
    End With

End Sub
```

Remove the DateAdd line at the end if your column A contains strings, not dates.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do this, but a simple one is (straight from the macro recorder of moving a range and overwriting the target):

```
Range("A3:G13").Cut Destination:=Range("A2:G12")
Range("A13").Select
```

Comment: It works but  i have a referenced table to this database table thus causing reference errors on the other table! Is there any other solution other than cutting?