# VBA code to overwrite cells through moving /shifting up a range of cells with a user input box

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I previously asked a question on [VBA code to overwrite cells through moving /shifting up a range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195214/vba-code-to-overwrite-cells-through-moving-shifting-up-a-range-of-cells) and i got an answer which met my needs. However i realised that i had to hard code all the ranges for each table to perform this vba function which is risky as the cell alignments often change in the sheet.. Thus i want an input box that allows user to select the table of cells they want to perform this function .I know how an input box works however the given code goes by rows and columns, something of which the range that the user selects, does not contain . Thus is there anyways for an input box to work in this code without having to hardcode? Or are there any other alternatives to avoid hardcording in this code and have it work based on the user selection basis? All of your help would be very much appreciated.

Improvised on the given answer but i am still getting a type mismatch error. Why is that so?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim y1 As Variant
Dim y2 As Variant
Dim x1 As Variant
Dim x2 As Variant

y1 = Application.InputBox("Input First Row", Type:=8)
y2 = Application.InputBox("Input End Row", Type:=8)
x1 = Application.InputBox("Input First Column", Type:=8)
x2 = Application.InputBox("Input End Column", Type:=8)

Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet ' or the specific sheet

    ' The 12 months
    For y = y1 To y2
        ' Your 7 columns
        For x = x1 To x2
            sh.Cells(y, x) = sh.Cells(y + 1, x)
        Next x
    Next y

    'With sh.Cells(y2, 1)
        '.Select
        ' This only works if your column A contains dates (not strings)
        '.Value = DateAdd("m", 1, sh.Cells(y2 - 1, 1))
   ' End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the accepted answer from your last question you could do something like this:

That way the User can select the range it acts on using input boxes?

```
Dim y1 As Variant
Dim y2 As Variant
Dim x1 As Variant
Dim x2 As Variant
Dim cell1 As Integer
Dim cell2 As Integer

y1 = Application.InputBox("Input First Row")
If y1 = "" Or y1 = False Then GoTo handleNull
y2 = Application.InputBox("Input End Row")
If y2 = "" Or y2 = False Then GoTo handleNull
x1 = Application.InputBox("Input First Column")
If x1 = "" Or x1 = False Then GoTo handleNull
x2 = Application.InputBox("Input End Column")
If x2 = "" Or x2 = False Then GoTo handleNull

cell1 = y2 - 1
cell2 = x1


Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, y As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet ' or the specific sheet

' The 12 months
For y = y1 To y2
    ' Your 7 columns
    For x = x1 To x2
        sh.Cells(y, x) = sh.Cells(y + 1, x)
    Next x
Next y

With sh.Cells(y2, 1)
    .Select
    ' This only works if your column A contains dates (not strings)
    .Value = DateAdd("m", 1, sh.Cells(cell1, cell2))
End With

handleNull:
End
```

Comment: What are you inputting as the values?

Comment: The respective column, row.

Comment: oh well that's because you're inputbox is now expecting a range. Mine was expecting integers

Comment: okay i changed it back to your code. it works perfectly now:) however if it is null inputs for all 4 boxes, it gives a programming error. How do i avoid it?

Comment: Well what do you want to do in that case? You could just have a check to see if any of the values are null and then either have a GOTO to end the macro or throw the inputbox again until a correct value is entered etc

Comment: In the case of  which the user accidentally clicks on the function?

Comment: Okay edited again. Now the User has a cancel button on each input box. Clicking this or clicking Okay with null entered will in both cases end the macro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89754/discussion-between-db579-and-niva).

Answer (score 1):

This will operate on the selected range:

```
Selection.Value = Selection.Offset(1,0).Value
```

Comment: But how do i put this . as in just one input box will do or?

Comment: Use can first select the range and then run the macro.